# Unable to run Outlook Add-In from Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, outlook-addin

I have built an Outlook Add-In on Visual Studio 17 , however i am not able to debug or run the code from Visual Studio.
It throws an exception(Attached).[image]

Any help would be appreciated to fix the issue,attaching the error screenshot for reference .

[image]

Comment: Looks like access is denied to a subfolder in the Temp folder. Does that folder actually exist?

Comment: The folder exists and i could actually run the .vsto file from the specified path.
However ,I cant debug or run the code from VS.

Comment: The deployment folder exists  in the temp folder and i could actually run a different .vsto file from the deployment folder, however i couldn't find the random sub folder and the .application file (C:\\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\40VQB827.151\11RKJACK.CYK.application)